# how can i make this flex box column layout like this?

Tags: css, flexbox

i am new to frontend developer.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <img src="//some image in here" alt="" class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto">
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <p class="text-justify noto-sans py-5" style="letter-spacing: 0.02em; line-height: 25px; font-size: 14px;"> some text in here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Layout**

How can I make the layout from 2 columns on laptop perspective into 1 column in responsive mobile with the width measure by 414px?

[This is the layout I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYSnB.png)

thank you for reading my question.

Comment: Ever heard of [CSS media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)?

Answer (score 5):

You can find out the [boostrap grid document here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options).

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
        <img src="//some image in here" alt="" class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto">
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
        <p class="text-justify noto-sans py-5" style="letter-spacing: 0.02em; line-height: 25px; font-size: 14px;"> some text in here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can find out the demo here: https://codepen.io/tuandaodev/pen/jOwzoVX

Answer (score 0):

**Bootstrap grid system**

- <576px -  Extra Small, you use class .col-1,.col-2,.col-3.....
  .col-12

  ≥576px -  Small, you use class .col-sm-1,.col-sm-2,.col-sm-3.....
  .col-sm-12

  ≥768px -  Medium, you use class .col-md-1,.col-md-2,.col-md-3.....
  .col-md-12

  ≥992px  -  Large, you use class .col-lg-1,.col-lg-2,.col-lg-3.....
  .col-lg-12

  ≥1200px -  Extra large, you use class
  .col-xl-1,.col-xl-2,.col-xl-3.....  .col-xl-12

  ≥1400px -  Extra extra large, you use class
  .col-xxl-1,.col-xxl-2,.col-xxl-3.....  .col-xxl-12

You can see more details- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/breakpoints/

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-12">
                <img src="//some image in here" alt="" class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-12">
                <p class="text-justify noto-sans py-5" style="letter-spacing: 0.02em; line-height: 25px; font-size: 14px;"> some text in here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```